# How to keep iphone anonymous from iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios-app-extension, ios-app-group

On an iOS device how would you prevent an application from setting an identifierforvendor for your device or is their a way to refresh the identifierforvendor without having to delete re download the iOS app.

The goal is I do not want an application to know my device through the identifierforvendor or through the advertiserID. The advertiserID I understand you can just refresh but the identifierforvendor requires deleting and re downloading to reset.

If anyone has any pointers. This is for a project I'm working on but it would be nice to the future as well to prevent ios apps from knowing my device.

Comment: that is a rather strange requirement, mind giving us some context? also which apps would know about your device... other apps on the device? the vendorID is on a per app basis, so one apps vendorID is different to another apps

Comment: If this is a programming question, please be much more specific. Also, I don't get which perspective you are talking from. Every app can just see it's own vendorid and nothing else.

Comment: My client has multiple accounts for one application but does not want those multiple accounts to be tied to one vendorID since they are logging into those multiple accounts through one device. For example, if you have multiple instagram accounts, instagram can see the one vendorID that you are logging in from for all those accounts and then see all of your behavior across all those different accounts. My client is fine if instagram tracks his behavior on for each individual account but to see his behavior across all accounts under one vendor ID feels like an invasion of privacy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. But it doesn't identify your iPhone. Nobody can find out who you are from the identifierForVendor. If 10 applications call identifierForVendor, they will get 10 different results.

Comment: If you have multiple accounts under one application then that application can track your behavior across those multiple accounts. It would be fine if that application were to track behavior for each individual account each with a unique vendorID but not my behavior across all accounts under one vendorID. Do you see what I mean? Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best way to keep multiple accounts anonymous from an iOS app is to delete and reinstall the app and then also to remember to refresh the advertiser ID. It's also very important to make sure that the app you are are working with doesn't have any partner apps using the same vendorID, you'll need to delete and reinstall those all as well.